# Directly Access RAM on AUTOSAR Environtment

Tags: autosar

I want to read value in RAM with given address and length of data. I have read several RTE API's and I think there is no API provide my needs. I hope there is API like `Rte_Ram_read(address,length)` or something else. I found API for access `PerInstanceMemory` or `InterRunnableVariable`, but they didn't work like what I want.

My question, Is there any API like what I want? or I have to create that by myself? or is there any advice for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is why do you want to do that?

The idea of a software component is that it is independent of the hardware and self-contained. To communicate with other components you should use ports. To communicate with runnables you should use `InterRunnableVariable` or `PerInstanceMemory`.

What's the use case behind reading something from RAM? Where does the data come from?

Comment: Thank you for your post @ZzetT. I already have a application which I want to change using AUTOSAR standard. In my mind, It would be easier to change my app if there is a RTE API like that. After further reading about autosar, I think you're totally right. My problem is, I want to create a SWC which I want to submit to ECU integrator, but even at this time I don't know the entire AUTOSAR system. So the thing that I can do for now is create SWC design but doesn't change the behavior. (as my boss said)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on which **SWC** puts the data in the RAM. The responsibility to define an interface is taken by this **SWC**.

I believe that it is according to **AUTOSAR** if you define a pointer to the desired address and read the value.
For example, if the value is 32-bit:

```
unsigned int * pAddr = (unsigned int *)0xYYYYZZZZ;
int value = *pAddr;
```

`0xYYYYZZZZ` is the address in the **RAM** that you want to read from. Normally, it should be `byte` aligned by `4`(depends on the processor).

Also you should take care for endianness(either big or little endian), because bytes may be in reversed order.

Comment: Thank for the answer. Technically your answer is correct but it seems not what I want since AUTOSAR didn't recommend that way of access. Especially we talk about SWC.